How can I sort a dictionary with in the dictionary by the keys of the second dictionary in python?
I have a dictionary as follows:
dict_1 ={'Spain':{'wins':1,'loses':0,'draws':2,'goal_difference':2, 'points':3},'Portugal':{'wins':3,'loses:1,'draws':1,'goal_difference':0,'points':4},'Morocco':{'wins':2,'loses':2,'draws':0,'goal_difference':-2,'points':3}}

I want to sort this dictionary first by the value of points then if the points are equal I want to sort this dictionary by the value wins and lastly if the wins are also equal I want to sort this based on the order of alphabets in keys. So the end result is something like this:
dict_1 ={'Portugal':{'wins':3,'loses:1,'draws':1,'goal_difference':0,'points':4},'Morocco':{'wins':2,'loses':2,'draws':0,'goal_difference':-2,'points':3}},'Spain':{'wins':1,'loses':0,'draws':2,'goal_difference':2, 'points':3}

How can I do this?
I know If I want to sort a dictionary based  on the values I can use lambda and sorted:
sorted(dict_1.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])

but I don't know how can I do this when I have dictionary with in the dictionary. I want to do this by lambda and sorted if possible.

See the duplicate. Since you have dict values, you need things like x[1]['points'] in the tuple in the lambda. It will be easier to read if you define a proper function with local variables as key.

Also if you need sort by multiple components you can just put those in a tuple, the records will be sorted by the first value, and if those are equal by the second, etc... Furthremore lambdas are just restricted inline function literals, if your sorting rules are too complex for a lambda to be readable you can just create a "real" function and return the sorting key (whatever it is).
